# WinRT Surface DirectX Black Screen

Tags: resize, windows-runtime, directx

I'm having a strange and irritating problem on WinRT Surface tablet when using DirectX (hosted in BackgroundSwapChainPanel). Basically once in a while (like once a day, or few times a week / while testing for few hours every day), half of my 3D scene goes black, like on the picture below (cut vertically or sometimes horizontally):

http://www.zurawcli.vot.pl/dxProblem.JPG

While this happens, the DirectX is still rensponsive and i have full control of the app.
I don't think posting code makes any sense ( i'm simply using standard SwapChain and resizing viewport and back texture whenever screen size changes - actually getting screen size from Core Window). This only happens once in a while : ( when i try to explicitly force this - like by splitting screen between two / switching between apps / and so on, I CANNOT repeat this error - viewport always resizes correctly. Then sometimes just using the app, this will happen.

Did anybody had any experience similliar to this ? Any ideas what is causing this ?
Thanks in advance,

cheers